# Trouble with PNAS template and accents in body and references

Tags: fonts, accents, font-encodings

This has been driving me nuts. I use the PNAS template and compile with `pdflatex` under MacOSX 10.9.2 and MacTeX 2013 or 2014 (tried both). Here's the very simple .tex file:

```
\documentclass{pnastwo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pnastwof}
\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\begin{article}
As introduced by Rodrigu\`{e}s \cite{rodr} initially ...

\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{rodr}Rodrigu\`{e}s B (2006) Title, \emph{Journal} 1(1):1--10.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{article}
\end{document}
```

The `pnastwof.sty` was edited to use the correct font names (phv* instead of ph* and ptm*8t instead of ti*).

**The problem** is that the accented è appears fine in the body but not in the references (appears as a strikeout Ł). If I use OT1 instead of T1 in `fontenc` (or do not use the fontenc package at all), then the situation reverses: fine in references, wrong in body. The `inputenc` package makes no difference.

The log warns about:

```
       : No file T1phvr.fd. on input line 12.
line 12: Font shape `T1/phvr/m/n' undefined(Font) using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead
       : Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

Is there a way to fix this cleanly without editing the `pnastwo` class or `pnastwof` package? Are the `\DeclareFontShape` definitions in the `pnastwof` package incomplete or wrong?

**My (ugly) solution** was to hack the `pnastwof` package and force the font encoding and family using `\def\bibfont{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{6pt}{8pt}\selectfont}` (overwriting the old \def\bibfont{...}). This change also gets rid of the missing font warnings in the log ...

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The `pnastwof` package is full of `\font` declarations that are ***evil***. The accent problem is due to the fact that the default font is a proprietary version of Frutiger that apparently has accents moved in different places.

If you want a preprint that is similar to the final result, avoid loading `pnastwof` and change the font setup. I really can't understand why the class and the package are written in this improper style. Leave to the copy editors do the appropriate changes.

```
\documentclass{pnastwo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%%% font setup in order to make the article printable
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand\bibfont{\fontsize{6pt}{9pt}\bfseries\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\bibitfont}{\bibfont\slshape}
\renewcommand{\bibbffont}{\bibfont}
%%%

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\begin{article}
As introduced by Rodrigu\'{e}s \cite{rodr} initially ...

\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{rodr} Rodrigu\'{e}s B (2006) Title, \emph{Journal} 1(1):1--10.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{article}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Improper style? You are being gentle. The PNAS class and package are atrocious. Your fix works for references but, alas, the class uses those custom frutiger fonts in a lot of places, e.g. figure/table captions, footnotes, etc., with plenty of quircks (e.g. italic/emph text is displayed as roman in a slightly different size). The frutiger fonts in the pnas class are links to helvetica (it's not the actual frutiger font, which is free on CTAN but not included in tex distributions). I worked out a more "gobal solution" but I can't answer my own question yet.

Answer (score 1):

After more digging, I worked out a solution which allows using the `pnastwof` package. The font name for the helvetica font suggested by PNAS are actually wrong. They should be `phvr*8t` instead of `phvr*`:

```
%% Karl Berry Names:
\def\helvetica{phvr8t}
\def\helveticaoblique{phvro8t}
\def\helveticaboldoblique{phvbo8t}
\def\helveticabold{phvb8t}
```

This then fixes the references accents issue.

As egreg also states in his answer, the class and package are pretty badly written. It would be ideal to ditch the `pnastwof` altogether but that's not so trivial.

The `pnastwo` class also defines frutiger fonts (links to helvetica) and then definitions based on them. It defines multiple font names for different sizes and styles instead of a family, which breaks the usage of \textit, \textbf, \em, \it, \bf etc. etc. in the sense that using any of these will result in the string displayed in roman font, rather than helvetica (serif).

egreg's solution addresses the references problem but figure captions, footnotes, abstract, title, author names, etc., all will still suffer as they use different font deifnitions (based on frutiger defs). So you have to either (i) redo those defs manually in the .tex as egreg did for \bib*font or else the ones in the `pnastwo` class will take effect and look ugly, (ii) edit the `pnaftwof` package or (iii) edit the frutiger and font definitions in the `pnaftwo` class and ditch the `pnaftwof` package. I went for (ii) ... the class is quite ugly.

Cheers

Comment: I had the same with pnaftwof but in the text and not in the references. My fix was to change the font lines as follows (instead of adding the 8t to helvetica fonts, for me it worked the other way around, i.e., removing the 8t from the times fonts): % Karl Berry Names: \def\timesroman{ptmr} \def\timesbold{ptmb} \def\timesitalic{ptmri} \def\timesbolditalic{ptmbi} % Karl Berry Names: \def\helvetica{phvr} \def\helveticaoblique{phvro} \def\helveticaboldoblique{phvbo} \def\helveticabold{phvb}