# siunitx does not detect typeface and size

Tags: siunitx, sharelatex

I am using a template from PNAS (http://www.pnas.org/site/authors/LaTex.xhtml) on sharelatex and when I am adding units like:

```
\SI{15}{\mL}
```

they are not scaled properly, as seen in the attached image.
[image: Example of siunitx not scaled properly]
Moreover, is there a way that I could force siunitx to use the surrounding fonts. I have tried to use in the preamble:

```
\sisetup{detect-weight=true, detect-family=true}
```

with no luck.
Any help would be appreciated.

#### Edit 1: Minimal example added

```
\documentclass{pnastwo}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage{gensymb,fixltx2e}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-weight=true, detect-family=true}

\begin{document}
\begin{article}
\begin{materials}
This is a minimal example. The following units \SI{15}{\mL} do not render with the same typeface and size as the surrounding text. 
\end{materials}
\end{article}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`? However, as far as I remember, the PNAS class uses a non standard system for fonts, which probably is responsible for tricking `siunitx`.

Comment: Have you switched to a font that does not include math symbols?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185661/trouble-with-pnas-template-and-accents-in-body-and-references

Comment: @egreg: I have just added an example to reproduce the problem. Thank you for the related article

Comment: As I told you, the `pnastwo` class uses a non standard method for fonts. In particular, the `materials` environment selects a font directly defined with the `\font` primitive, which makes packages that assume compliance with the standard font selection scheme fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class doesn't use nfss to define fonts and so siunitx has absolutly no chance to detect the font (and as a side-warning: be careful with non-ascii chars. In the combination with xelatex/lualatex they can come out wrong or be missing all together). You can get around the problem by redefining the font commands:

```
\documentclass{pnastwo}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage{gensymb,fixltx2e}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\renewcommand\materialfont{\sffamily\fontsize{7pt}{\baselineskip}\selectfont}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-weight=true, detect-family=true}

\begin{document}
\begin{article}
\begin{materials}
This is a minimal example. The following units \SI{15}{\mL} do not render with the same typeface and size as the surrounding text.
\end{materials}
\end{article}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think this will be accepted by PNAS, because they seem to use proprietary fonts and they *don't* use the NFSS, because the fonts are encoded in a nonstandard way.

Comment: @egreg: Well the OP loads fontspec which is leads to an unstandard font setup anyway. Beside this the default value of `\materialfont` is cmss at 7pt, so the font (without fontspec) would be the same.

Comment: `fontspec` conforms to the NFFS, which is what I mean by "standard”. The `pnastwo` class defines `\materialfont` in that way just for the author's galley, but the final printout will use Frutiger.

Comment: @egreg: But it this case a document meant for submission shouldn't load fontspec at all. It will quite probably clash somewhere.

Comment: That goes without saying.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: That did the trick for the moment. Thank you all.

Comment: @jiko: but I hope you did understand that this will not work if you submit the document.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer & egreg: I do understand and I am aware. There is a long way until submission...

Answer (score 1):

(Too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer of sorts.)

There must be something going on in your document setup you haven't told us about so far. The `pnastwo` document class does not, by itself, mess with fonts, at least not in a way that would affect the macros of the `\siunitx` package.

Please do tell us -- ideally in the form of an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) -- how you go about changing the text font to sans-serif.

[image]

```
\documentclass{pnastwo}
\usepackage[detect-family=true]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
abc

\SI{15}{\milli\liter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try loading the `pnastwof` package, that's requested by the template.

Comment: @Mico: When I am adding \sffamily the whole paragraph changes typeface. I have edited my question adding an example. Thank you.